NX CreateDependenciesError: Failed to create dependencies. (See above for errors)
Lately, I've been getting simply the error in the title when running targets eg. build, test, graph, lint etc. whenever something breaks in the config files or folder/file setup in my NX monorepo workspace.
The See above for errors is misleading since there are no meaningful details posted in the trace.
example -
I created a new nx library and updated config files and now I can't run any targets in my workspace. If I do run a target, I get this error -

user@user my-repo % npx nx test my-lib
NX   Failed to create dependencies. See above for errors
Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

When I run the target with --verbose, I get the following -

user@user my-repo % npx nx test my-lib --verbose
NX   Failed to create dependencies. See above for errors
CreateDependenciesError: Failed to create dependencies. See above for errors
at buildProjectGraphUsingContext (/Users/user/frontend/my-repo/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/build-project-graph.js:138:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at buildProjectGraphUsingProjectFileMap (/Users/user/frontend/my-repo/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/build-project-graph.js:68:24)
at createAndSerializeProjectGraph (/Users/user/frontend/my-repo/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:229:55)
at processFilesAndCreateAndSerializeProjectGraph (/Users/user/frontend/my-repo/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:160:19)
at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/user/frontend/my-repo/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:84:13)

As you can see there are no details posted above the NX error line and the stack trace doesn't have anything specific any file that I would have touched during the buildProjectGraphUsingContext call in the info.

is:question user:1234 "words here"
